# about asp.net MVC Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am using asp.net mvc 2 here i have a following class Applicant and it has its properties 
which are mentioned [Required] so if i add a new view in project of strongly type with Applicant Class and use only one property from applicant class Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Property1) and when i use Model.IsValid it return **False** because i have not used supplied value for other required properties (property2,property3,property4). **So is there any way for using same Applicant Class For different view and also validate only those Properties which i have used in view not those which have not used in view.**

```
class Applicant{

 [Required]
 propert1{get,set;}
 [Required]
 propert2{get,set;}
 [Required]
 propert3{get,set;}
 [Required]
 propert4{get,set;}

}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to create according view models for views? You are trying to keep it too DRY which leads to violation of single responsibility principle.

Comment: @user460293 DRY stands for Don't repeat yourself. in Your case - view model serves more than one view but it would be easier just to create multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way for using same Applicant Class For different view and also validate only those Properties which i have used in view not those which have not used in view.

I would recommend you creating view models for each view and having validation properties adapted to the needs of each view.

Comment: thanks ok i will do that but can we do what i am asking for? i think it is clearly NO

Comment: @user460293, no you can't because data annotation validation attributes are baked at compile time and you cannot modify/remove some of them dynamically based on which action is being executed. Also that would be bad design.